# Azure CI and CD with NBGV

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, versioning

We're using NB.GV in our CI pipeline like:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: custom
    custom: tool
    arguments: install --tool-path . nbgv --ignore-failed-sources
  displayName: Install NBGV tool

- script: nbgv cloud -c -a
  displayName: Set Version
```

It sets the version correctly, so in further tasks, we're able to use them (e.g. $(GitBuildVersion))

The problem comes when we're trying to setup a CD pipeline based on [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/ui-testing-for-windows-apps-with-winappdriver-and-appium-azure/ba-p/829173) article. There we need to read `$(Build.BuildNumber)` which has a different value than expected. Based on [official documentation](https://github.com/dotnet/Nerdbank.GitVersioning/blob/master/doc/cloudbuild.md) it should be e.g. **1.3.1.57621** but we're getting **1.3.1+g15e1898f47**.

It seems like *AssemblyInformationalVersion* and *BuildVersion* got exchanged.

We have set `setVersionVariables: true` in version.json.

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: NGBV sets BuildNumber and this is what this tool does. So can you explain what specific problem you have here?

Comment: In our case, it sets the BuildNumber incorectly in CD (Releases). We are expecting something like **1.3.1.57621** but instead, we're getting **1.3.1+g15e1898f47**. Need to mention that in whole CI pipeline it is ok. When starting a new Release, BuildNumber is set to **1.3.1+g15e1898f47** instead of **1.3.1.57621** as it should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You my add this after running ngbv to update you BuildNumber

```
      - powershell: Write-Host "##vso[build.updatebuildnumber]$(GitBuildVersion)"
        displayName: 'Update build number to $(GitBuildVersion)'
```

According to this you should have then expected value:
[image]

You may also check what variables you have by running `- bash: env | sort`